# WPF automatic resize font until it fits within parent control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, font-size

I have a user control who's root element is a Grid.

I also have have a ContentControl that serves as a placeholder for some text that is filled when data is loaded. This control can be moved around within the user control and so it's position can be anywhere.

If the text is too long to fit within the root Grid of the user control, I want to reduce the font size of the ContentControl until the text fits.

My problem is that I can't seem to find an event that I can handle to do this process.
I tried using the ContentControl.LayoutUpdated event;however, the sender parameter for this always appears to be nothing...which is really not helpful!

I am really looking forward to any advise on how to achieve this.

Thank you

-Frinny

Comment: You could surround the ContentControl with a ViewBox that will scale the ContentControl to fit in the grid. Is this an option?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Wrapping your `ContentControl` in a `Viewbox` set to only scale down will do this for you:

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
    <ContentControl Content="Some Text"/>
</Viewbox>
```