# WPF scale text to fit only when too big

Tags: c#, wpf, scale, truncate

I am trying to setup a list of items in WPF which contains strings of random length (people's names).  The majority of them are generally within a certain size, but occasionally you come across a string so long that it runs out of the bounds of it's container.  I've normally just truncated it when it's too long, but I would much rather show the entirety of the string.

How can I force the text to remain it's normal size, unless too big to fit...in which case scale it down to fit?

NOTE:  This is not the same as scaling all text to fit a certain size, which is accomplished using a viewbox around the text

IE:  This is NOT what I want:

```
<Viewbox MaxWidth="100">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeDisplayName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Viewbox>
```

This makes everything scale up when too small, as well as scale down when too big.  I ONLY want it to scale down when too big and NEVER scale up when too small...

Any thoughts?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881683/wpf-automatic-resize-font-until-it-fits-within-parent-control

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a `Viewbox` but set its [StretchDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `DownOnly`.

```
<Viewbox MaxWidth="100" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeDisplayName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Man, I could NOT find this at all from Google, what a simple fix lol.  I figured the WPF guys had thought about this at some point or another...Thanks